# Embedded iframe is prompted for security certificate

Tags: apache, iframe, certificate

Running WAMP and I'm trying to embed an iframe of an external website (mcmaster) in a dokuwiki and I'm getting a security alert that doesn't allow the site to be displayed. Security alert says the sites certificate isn't good, and I didn't get the option to allow the page in the iframe but if i opened in a new window i got the option to. So after allowing it just returns a blank screen. What do I need to enable or exception to add in Apache to allow the server to embed this website? Apologies if this is in the wrong stack but I assume this is a server issue not a coding issue, as other sites work fine with the syntax.

Comment: Sounds like a browser or server configuration option to me, off topic which either way.

Comment: I posted to serverfault but was redirected here.

Comment: Ouch, that's just unfair. I'll vote up, but I'm not sure if this is the place. Maybe somebody knows how to fix this using code though...